# Bluetooth device is not available?

Tags: raspbian, peripherals, bluetooth

I followed [this tutorial](https://www.modmypi.com/blog/installing-the-raspberry-pi-nano-bluetooth-dongle) to set up my Bluetooth dongle and get it running.  I have [the same Bluetooth dongle that is in the tutorial](https://www.modmypi.com/nano-bluethooth-dongle), yet I can not seem to get it to work.  I get to step "C" and then I run into problems.  Here is some commands I ran to diagnose the problem:

```
$ hcitool scan
Device is not available: No such device
$ lsusb
...
Bus 001 Device 009: ID 0a12:0001 Cambridge Silicon Radio, Ltd Bluetooth Dongle (HCI mode)
...
$ hciconfig dev
hci0:   Type: BR/EDR  Bus: USB
        BD Address: 00:1B:10:00:2A:EC  ACL MTU: 1017:8  SCO MTU: 64:0
        DOWN
        RX bytes:1355 acl:0 sco:0 events:49 errors:0
        TX bytes:204 acl:0 sco:0 commands:48 errors:0
$ hciconfig -a
hci0:   Type: BR/EDR  Bus: USB
        BD Address: 00:1B:10:00:2A:EC  ACL MTU: 1017:8  SCO MTU: 64:0
        DOWN
        RX bytes:1355 acl:0 sco:0 events:49 errors:0
        TX bytes:204 acl:0 sco:0 commands:48 errors:0
        Features: 0xff 0xff 0x8d 0xfe 0x9b 0xf9 0x00 0x80
        Packet type: DM1 DM3 DM5 DH1 DH3 DH5 HV1 HV2 HV3
        Link policy:
        Link mode: SLAVE ACCEPT
$ hcitool dev
Devices:
$ sudo hciconfig hci0 piscan
Can't set scan mode on hci0: Network is down (100)
$ sudo hciconfig hci0 reset
Can't init device hci0: Operation not supported (95)
$ /etc/init.d/bluetooth status
[ ok ] bluetooth is running.
$ sudo bluez-simple-agent
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/bluez-simple-agent", line 104, in <module>
    path = manager.DefaultAdapter()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dbus/proxies.py", line 70, in __call__
    return self._proxy_method(*args, **keywords)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dbus/proxies.py", line 145, in __call__
    **keywords)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dbus/connection.py", line 651, in call_blocking
    message, timeout)
dbus.exceptions.DBusException: org.bluez.Error.NoSuchAdapter: No such adapter
```

Any suggestions? Power isn't the issue since I'm running the dongle from a powered USB hub.

**I do not want solutions that tell me to downgrade my software.  That is not a solution, that is a workaround.**

Comment: What are you powering from the hub the bluetooth dongle, the Pi or both?

Comment: @SteveRobillard Just the dongle.

Comment: What is returned from /etc/init.d/bluetooth status

Comment: @SteveRobillard Edited it in at the bottom of what commands I ran.  It said it was running.

Comment: What did you get for: `hcitool dev`? Since bluetooth seems to be running on the Raspberry Pi, did you check that bluetooth on your mobile device is discoverable? Also check [this guide](http://rootprompt.apatsch.net/2013/04/23/raspberry-pi-network-audio-player-pulseaudio-dlna-and-bluetooth-a2dp-part-3-bluetooth/) and [this guide](http://www.instructables.com/id/Turn-your-Raspberry-Pi-into-a-Portable-Bluetooth-A/step4/Modify-some-config-files-to-enable-our-Bluetooth-e/).

Comment: I edited in the outputs of that command and some more from the links. Yes, my mobile device is discoverable.

Comment: I'm having exactly the same error as you.
Did you by chance got any update on this?

Comment: @catteneo No, I'm considering offering a bounty on this question soon to get an answer.

Comment: I have the same issue. The output from bluetooth status is:

root@raspbmc:/home/pi# /etc/init.d/bluetooth status
[ ok ] bluetooth is running
would love any input

Comment: from what I've read; it just depends on the exact make and model of your BT dongle.  Some work fine, others don't.  If that's not the case I would love to hear how to fix it

Comment: but the bluetooth dongle is listed with lsusb ...hcitool scan will only show bluetooth devices around you, not the usb dongle... didi you startx and tried the bluetooth manager?

Comment: @Francis But the company that sold them only sells Raspberry Pi merchandise, I feel as if the device should work.

Comment: @thorb I have tried that, the bluetooth manager wasn't working properly.

Comment: did you try to open the bt man from the bar at the bottom? (the little icon on the right side in the bottom bar, open with mouse right-click)

Comment: @thorb Yep, the GUI bluetooth manager was acting funny and didn't work.

Comment: Just because it is listed in lsusb doesn't mean it works. `org.bluez.Error.NoSuchAdapter:` <- that error, as ambiguous as it sounds, kind of means it cannot open the port to the `hci` profile of the Bluetooth protocol. This, unfortunately is a vendor specific issue, where the software is requesting a GUID "Profile" that doesn't exits. I had this issues with SPP, and it a bloody nightmare to get working. Possibly because the vendor used an out of date specification or uses a custom GUID that is no longer supported in the latest version of what ever you are using. Try and find working dongles

Comment: Hi- Did you find a solution? Could you please post an answer and accept it. Thanks

Answer (score 9):

Late answer, but recently experienced it. I noticed the interface is down. Yours is down too.

Running `sudo hciconfig hci0 up` on an *updated firmware* solved my problem. Not sure how that happened, as the people from [this raspberrypi.org thread](http://www.raspberrypi.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=63418&p=469478) insists on downgrading.

Comment: This worked for me, after i unblocked the bluetooth interface with `rfkill`

Answer (score -2):

Check my answer in the following thread:
http://www.raspberrypi.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=63418&p=469478

I had the same issue with the same dongle and been able to solve it downgrading the RPi kernel (raspbian).

Cheers,

Olivier

Comment: This answer needs to be re-written to incorporate details from that other thread to better make a complete question/answer pair here.